# Why does my bash script not run properly on every docker container that starts up?

Tags: bash, docker

My Dockerfile copies an init.sh script to the container.

```
# DOCKERFILE

FROM ubuntu:latest

# a bunch of installation commands

COPY init.sh /

ENTRYPOINT bash init.sh

EXPOSE 80
```

And I have a docker-compose file with 2 services:

- Service1: This service is being scaled.
- Service2: Database

I have it so that when the Service1 container starts up, this script will run.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script

# Missing files directory
if [[ ! -e /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files ]]; then
    mkdir /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files
    chmod a+w /var/www/drupal/sites/default/files
fi

# Missing settings file
cp /var/www/drupal/sites/default/default.settings.php /var/www/drupal/sites/default/settings.php
chmod a+w /var/www/drupal/sites/default/settings.php

# Install Drush & Install Drupal
cd /var/www/drupal && composer require --dev drush/drush
cd /var/www/drupal && vendor/bin/drush site-install standard \
--db-url=mysql://root:random@mariadb:3306/drupaldb -y \
--site-name=ExampleWebsite \
--account-name=random \
--account-pass=random

 # Post-Installation Steps
chmod go-w /var/www/drupal/sites/default/settings.php
chmod go-w /var/www/drupal/sites/default

cd /var/www/drupal && vendor/bin/drush cache-rebuild

/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
```

However, when I run the command to start up the containers along with --scale `docker-compose up -d --scale Service1=5`, some of the containers run the script properly on start up but some don't. For the ones that don't, I would have to go into the container and manually run the script, then it's fine.

Shouldn't all the containers be the same and would've run the same script properly?
Instead, I would have to manually go into some of the containers and run the script.

Comment: What do you mean by run properly? What is the exact content of the script? And what is the exact problem? Why don't you do installation commands in a Dockerfile and build your image once so that you don't even have to do these installation commands on container start?

Comment: I've added content now. The problem is that when the containers start up, only some of the containers have the drupal installation completed with the site up. Otherwise for the containers where the script doesn't work, I would just see the drupal installation wizard when I head to the browser. The script should install drupal properly without the installation wizard appearing on container start up. The drupal containers have to connect to the database so I can't run that in the Dockerfile.

Comment: That script is not exactly written with a significant level of paranoia. Using `|| exit`s would help a great deal (as a [less-unsafe alternative to `set -e`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)). `set -x` would also be helpful to track what's going on, in conjunction with recording stderr from a failed run. That said, an `ENTRYPOINT` should be something that takes an invocation's arguments and does something useful with them; your script doesn't do that at all -- it looks like it's just throwing its arguments away. You probably want that script to be a `CMD` instead of an `ENTRYPOINT`.